# How do I load a UV map onto a 3d mesh in 3d View

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

I was editing my UV map and it suddenly disappeared from the character model I was working on. How do I make it reappear on the model? I am new to blender so I don't really know what is going on.

Gyazo: https://gyazo.com/429358278e2083d4058166dc6d32b51b

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in a material using nodes for the object then, use my example here:
*I recommend pressing Cltr + T on the image for a better time editing.

If you don't known how to get there, there are loads of tutorial online for you to use[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the 3D view menu on the bottom, you can switch between modes, you can switch it to either texture or material mode to see your UV[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving this response but unfortunately it does not solve my issue. Here is a picture of the whole window. I have tried both material and texture but it still does not reappear. Any other suggestions would be helpful: https://gyazo.com/8c567c1d11aecae2859bd1f6d427a7df